# how to calculate age group in google data studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to have a calculated field for the age group. I have below code but I keep receiving the error message: Failed to create field. Please try again later.

```
CASE
WHEN AGE < 19 and age > 0 THEN "BELOW 18"
WHEN AGE > 18 AND AGE < 26 THEN "18 ~ 25"
WHEN AGE > 25 AND AGE < 31 THEN "26 ~ 30"
WHEN AGE > 30 AND AGE < 36 THEN "31 ~ 35"
WHEN AGE > 35 AND AGE < 41 THEN "36 ~ 40"
WHEN AGE > 40 THEN "ABOVE 40"
when age is NULL THEN "Not Provided"
else "Not Provid"
END
```

where age is calculated as below

```
FLOOR(DATE_DIFF(created_at,birthday)/365)
```

can anyone help me with this? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late but i did something similar and i hope it could help you or someone, and what i did was:

Age:

```
DATETIME_DIFF(TODAY('your timezone'),birth_date,year)
```

Where the timezone you can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) just use the TZ database name

And for the CASE scenario it was similar

```
case
when Age >= 0 and Age < 10 then "0-9"
when Age > 9 and Age < 18 then "10-17"
when Age > 17 and Age < 26 then "18-25"
when Age > 25 and Age < 40 then "26-39"
when Age > 39 and Age < 66 then "40-64"
when Age > 64 then "65+"
else "Not provided"
end
```

Comment: Semantically speaking, there is no difference from the first code to the second one. The real answer is that Data Studio is buggy when validating formulas, so sometimes the workaround is to make small changes in the source (add/remove parenthesis, reverse parameters, use different functions, etc) to hack this validation until it passes.